# Can't perform React state update on an unmounted component. To fix cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error =

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:174:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:34:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:85:4 in printWarning
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:61:16 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19758:13 in warnAboutUpdateOnUnmountedFiberInDEV
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17689:40 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7350:25 in classComponentUpdater.enqueueSetState
at node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:365:2 in Component.prototype.setState
at http://192.168.0.166:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:185915:30 in _callee$
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:165:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:177:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:437:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:388:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:132:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:131:4 in flushedQueue
```

I am not getting in which screen I have problem I have lots of screen. please help. to debug so I can at least know in which screen I have probelm.

Comment: When this warning pops up in the console, it's most likely the previous screen you've been on.